# SQl issue adding a char before id field , how?

Tags: sql, sql-update

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(id varchar,
sal int);

insert into customer values (1,500);
insert into customer values (2,500);
insert into customer values (3,500);
insert into customer values (4,500);
select * from customer;

update customer set id = 'sss'+id;

select * from customer;
```

[My ideone link](http://ideone.com/Env2K)

I missed the 'sss' word before the id while creating, I thought update would do it, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update customer set id = 's' || cast(id as varchar(10));
```

[Works in your IdeOne environment.](http://ideone.com/3ecqN)